Xmobar ignores "-w"
Here is my Xmobar config file:
  import Xmobar

  config :: Config
  config =
    defaultConfig
      { font = "FiraCode Nerd Font;8",
        allDesktops = True,
        lowerOnStart = True,
        overrideRedirect = True,
        position = BottomH 30,
        alpha = 200,
        commands =
          [ Run XMonadLog,
            -- Run $ DiskU [("/", "HD: <usedbar> (<used>/<size>)")] ["-L", "0", "-H", "85", "-n", "green", "-h", "red", "-b", "="] 20,
            Run $ Memory ["t", "Mem: <usedratio>%"] 10,
            Run $ Kbd [],
            Run $
              MultiCpu
                ["-t", "<autovbar>", "-w", "30", "-L", "3", "-H", "50", "--normal", "green", "--high", "red"]
                10,
            Run $ Date "%a %_d %b %Y <fc=#ee9a00>%H:%M:%S</fc>" "date" 10,
            Run $ XPropertyLog "_XMONAD_TRAYPAD"
          ],
        template = "%XMonadLog% }{ | %multicpu% | %kbd% | %memory% | %memory% | %date% | %_XMONAD_TRAYPAD%",
        -- template = "%XMonadLog% }{ %kbd% | %multicpu% | %memory% | %date%",
        alignSep = "}{"
      }

  main :: IO ()
  main = xmobar config

I want the MultiCpu section be of constant width, lets say 30 charachters wide.
As you can see, I use the "-w", but it has no effect.
I expected my CPU section to be of constatn 30 characters length, but its not, it varies in width all the time.

For future googlers: I've solved the issue by changing the font to a mono font.
